# list of Week numbers from given month in php

Tags: php, date

I have to list the week numbers for a given months.

Lets say my input should be 2(feb)
my output should be the list of week number in feb (5, 6, 7)

please help me in this

Thanks

Comment: Is the 2 simply the month number for february? or something else (especially as you're only listing 3 week numbers for february)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = "2(feb)";

// parse the input string to extract the month
list(,$month) = sscanf($input,'%d(%[^)]s)');

// Get timestamp for the 1st day of the requested month (using current year)
$startMonth = strtotime('1-'.$month);
// Get the ISO week number for the 1st day of the requested month
$startWeek = date('W',$startMonth);

// Get timestamp for the last day of the requested month (using current year)
$endMonth = strtotime('+1 Month -1 Day',$startMonth);
// Get the ISO week number for the last day of the requested month
$endWeek = date('W',$endMonth);

// get a range of weeks from the start week to the end week
if ($startWeek > $endWeek) {
    // start week for january in previous year
    $weekRange = range(1,$endWeek);
    array_unshift($weekRange,intval($startWeek));
} else {
    $weekRange = range($startWeek,$endWeek);
}

var_dump($weekRange);
```

Comment: This won't play well for Januaries having the first of the month belonging to ISO week 52/53.

Comment: @salathe - true. At the moment, I'd still like some feedback from the OP on why his request only lists 3 weeks rather than 5, so this is only really a quick-and-dirty method until he explains what it is he really wants.... but fixed that anyway

Comment: @MarkBaker what if I wanted to leave out weeks not belonging to the current year?  
e.g. `date('W', strtotime('31 Dec 2012'))` returns me 1..

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWeekRange($month=1){
  $dt = new \DateTime('first Monday of this month');
  $startWeek = date('W',strtotime($dt->format('Y-m-d')));
  $currentWeek = date('W');
  $weeks_in_month = weeks_in_month($month,date('Y'));
  $endWeek = $startWeek+($weeks_in_month-1);



  $weekRange =array();
  for($i=$startWeek;$i<=$endWeek;$i++){

    $weekRange[] = $i;
  }
  print_r($weekRange);}
```